# Etymology of "If I had my druthers..."

Tags: etymology, pronunciation-vs-spelling, phrase-origin, historical-change, eye-dialect

I understand the phrase, "If I had my druthers..." to mean, "If I had my way," as in:

> If I had my druthers, we'd all have Mondays off and work a half day on Saturdays and Sundays.

EtymologyOnline.com gives the following note for [*druthers*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=druthers&searchmode=none):

> 1895, from jocular formation based on *I'd ruther*, Amer.Eng. dialectal form of *I'd rather* (used by Bret Harte as drathers, 1875).

But I'm curious how this morphed into, "If I had my druthers." It would seem that the saying would be:

> Druthers have Mondays off and work a half day on Saturdays and Sundays.

Also, I'm curious as to the etymology / first use of the full phrase, "If I had my druthers..."

Comment: _Druthers_ is taken to be essentially equivalent to _preference_, and _*Preference have Mondays off and work a half day on Saturdays and Sundays_ wouldn't be acceptable, so it shouldn't seem like _Druthers have Mondays off..._ should be the form of the saying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The online [Merriam-Webster says](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/druthers) the first known use is from 1870, and [The Phrase Finder quotes](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/194850.html) the January 1870 edition of *Overland Monthly and Out West Magazine* as having this:

> If I was a youngster, I 'drather set up in any perfession but a circus-driver, but a man can't always have his 'drathers.

I believe that is likely the form that the first usages took, and shows the humorous intent of the phrase, with the "punch" of the humor coming at the end of the line.  (It also shows its use in American dialect writing, and perhaps that it hadn't stabilized on the *druthers* spelling/pronunciation.)

Further research shows an earlier instance, one which shows the same structure.  It is from an "Original Dialog" section of the 22 August 1868 issue of *Oliver Optic's magazine: Our boys and girls*.  The piece, [*Before Vacation* by Peregrine Breese](http://books.google.com/books?id=4DNAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA540&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false), has this passage:

> *Isabella.* I am sure I don't care what any of you like; but Saratoga or Newport I still cling to; there, now.
>
> *Susan.* There was a queer old lady in our neighborhood, who used to say, "Well, some druther have this, and some druther have that; but all of us can't have our druthers." We shall see!

This seems unlikely to be the earliest use, but perhaps nearly so, and is likely to have something like the style of the original use.

Comment: A still earlier usage, from 1859, is found in [_Knitting-work: A Web of Many Textures_](http://books.google.com/books?id=WTpIAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA359), p. 359.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that "If I had my druthers" = "If I had my 'I'd rather'" = "If I had my say" = "If I were to say my opinion".

I think it fits perfectly. Anyone agrees with me?

Comment: This seems likely: it's converting a phrase into a noun, similar to how you might talk about "could haves" and "should haves", using them as nouns, or indeed "ifs" and "buts".

Answer (score 2):

***Early 'druthers' in New England***

I ran a Google Books search for early instances of "druthers" and found, in addition to the 1868 instance from *Our Boys and Girls* mentioned in mgkrebbs's answer, this one from Benjamin Shillaber, "[Mrs. Partington Grows Desultory](https://books.google.com/books?id=WTpIAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA359&dq=%22druthers%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjPo-jZxNP0AhVFbc0KHQMHCcIQ6AF6BAgFEAI#v=onepage&q=%22druthers%22&f=false)," in *Knitting-Work: A Web of Many Textures* (1859):

> "There's many a slip 'twixt the cup and the lip," said Mrs. Partington, with a philosophical upraising of the index-finger, putting her specs up on her head, "and it's no use to be particular about the portion which Providence sends us; for, however much we may say we'd rather have this and we'd rather have that, we can't any of us have the **druthers** that we want. It has been said that doubtful things is very uncertain, and that we can't tell who's to be mayor till after election ; and that reminds me to say that them that buys the most of cheap goods has to pay the most for 'em, and heaven knows when the costiveness of the times will be any better." She ran down here, like an eight-day clock, and those who heard her wondered at the wisdom of her remarks, which, though they couldn't make out what it all meant, glistened in the light of affectionate partiality, like a piece of glass beneath the rays of the moon.

I should note that mgkrebbs also cites this 1859 instance, in a follow-up comment beneath his (if he is indeed Krebbs, Maynard G.) main answer.

[Shillaber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_Penhallow_Shillaber) was a popular writer and humorist who grew up in New Hampshire and lived most of his adult life in Boston and other parts of Massachusetts.

Then, as cited in mgkrebbs's main answer, from Peregrine Breese, "[Before Vacation](https://books.google.com/books?id=FDgN4K_FpbYC&pg=PA540&dq=%22druthers%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTuvvr_9X0AhVCB50JHVZbBhIQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22druthers%22&f=false)," in *Our Boys and Girls* (August 22, 1868):

> Susan. There was a queer old lady in our neighborhood, who used to say, "Well, some druther have this, and some druther have that; but all of us can't have our **druthers**." We shall see! Here is little Dora, now, still as a mouse: what does she say?

*Our Boys and Girls* was published in Boston, but I could find no information on "Peregrine Breese" through a Google search. Nevertheless,  I get the very strong impression that "the queer old lady in our neighborhood" whom Susan in 1868 mentions is none other than Mrs. Partington, as the language 1n the 1868 instance is extremely similar to the language in the 1859 instance.

Other instances of *druthers* show up in the 1870s and early 1880s. For example, from E.P.C., "[Sunday Talk](https://books.google.com/books?id=tEYbAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA75&dq=%22druthers%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTuvvr_9X0AhVCB50JHVZbBhIQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=%22druthers%22&f=false)," in *The Dayspring* (May 1872):

> "Martha says we can't have our ***Druthers*** in this world."
>
> "***Druthers***?" asked Sarah; "what does that mean?"
>
> "Do you know, Louisa?"
>
> "You must take what you can get, as you can't have what you'd rather have. What queer words Martha uses."

*The Dayspring*, formerly *Sunday-School Gazette*, was a monthly publication of the Unitarian Sunday-School Society of Boston. I have no idea who E.P.C. was.

From Rebecca Clarke, [*Quinnebasset Girls*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015039750461&view=1up&seq=45&q1=druthers) (1877):

> "Is your father dead?"
>
> "Why of course he is, or I shouldn't be here. He died before I can remember, and my mother—she was a poor little feeble thing, not much bigger than you are—went off up to the 'Forks,' and tried to keep a boarding-house, but after a while *she* broke don and died. Oh, well," added Charles, preparing to whistle, "I'd rather have had a home, and been brought up *like* folks, but you can't have all your ***druthers***. Hope you won't set me down for a regular ninny because I whined so when you first came into the room."

According to the Wikipedia page about her, [Clarke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebecca_Sophia_Clarke) "spent most of her life in her native town of Norridgewock, Maine," although she did teach in Indiana for ten years.

---

***Early 'druthers' elsewhere in the U.S.***

From Clara Tadlock, "[Moved to Town](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=loc.ark:/13960/t6k07rb2x&view=1up&seq=111&skin=2021&q1=druthers)," in Clara Tadlock, *Solomon Grinder's Christmas Eve and Other Poems* (1885):

> But there hain't much comfort livin' / (This world's a fleetin' show!) / I'd d'ruther be back a farmin', / But they—well—they wouldn't go! / A body cain't have their **druthers**!— / How be I? pow'ful weak / Sometimes!—I guess it's rheumatics—/ Hed 'em more'n a week.

[Tadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clara_Moyse_Tadlock) was originally from Southampton, England, but emigrated to the U.S. when she was eight years old and lived in Ohio, Illinois, and Tennessee. The poem's narrator is evidently a farmer who recently left farming to live in town after discovering coal on his property.

The first close match for the pattern "if X had X's druthers" appears in Louise Andrews,  "[Christmas Among the Bugs](https://newspapers.library.in.gov/cgi-bin/indiana?a=d&d=IJ18860110.1.11&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-%22his+druthers%22------)," in the *Indianapolis [Indiana] Journal* (January 10, 1886):

> "Daddy Longlegs say dat one drink of spring-branch water's worth more to him den all de yellow-label bran’s of champagne, let alone de bottle of sweet cider he foun’ in his stocking, an’ camiliky little ole Billy Cricket say dat ef he had his **druthers**, he’d druther have one tender, juicy spear of grass dan two sets of Emerson!

This is quite a leap from Mrs. Partington of New England, but if nothing else it suggests the spread of *druthers* in the 27 years from 1859 to 1886. Louise Andrews may be [Marie Louise Andrews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marie_Louise_Andrews), who lived in Indiana for much of her life and was "a ready and versatile writer of poems, essays, and sketches, contributing to various periodical publications," according to Wikipedia.

From "[Geo. O. Barnes. Praise the Lord. God Is Love and Nothing Else](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85052020/1886-07-13/ed-1/seq-1/#words=%22his%2Bdruthers%22)," in the *[Stanford, Kentucky] Semi-weekly Interior Journal* (July 13, 1886):

> I have not yet been to my cabin [aboard a steamship crossing the Pacific Ocean from Auckland to San Francisco] yet to sleep. The very thought is suffocating. I lie around on settee or chairs or floor, as I wish. The largest latitude of liberty is sympathetically accorded on ship board, at such a time, and passengers do pretty much as they please. Blessed license is it to crawl around with one's wretchedness a bit, instead of having it aggravated by close confinement. Some are in such a state of hopeless collapse that they drop into a stifling bunk of a little stuffy cabin and lie there in limp, perspiring despair, refusing to move. To me it is an intense relief to crawl around. But every one has his "**druthers**." There is perhaps very little' choice in sea sickness.

However, the earliest exact match for "If I had my druthers..." that I could find is from Richard Johnston, "[Black Spirits and White](https://books.google.com/books?id=MEoazbh_facC&pg=PA311&dq=%22druthers%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHvfS4ytP0AhWDK80KHU4tBIo4ChDoAXoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22druthers%22&f=false)," in *Harper's Young People* (March 5, 1889), where it appears in speech attributed to a Black character:

> "What kid [of spirits] you axin' about, Marse Tommmy, white spayits er blck spayits? percase dey is deffer'nt." He answered with respect, but solemnly.
>
> "Both; but I thought all of 'em were white."
>
> "In gen'l dee is; but some un'em is black , an'dem's de kind dat, **ef I had my 'druthers** , I'd ruther not come up wid 'em sildom."

[Richard Malcolm Johnston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Malcolm_Johnston) was from Georgia but lived in Maryland from the close of the Civil War until his death in 1898.

Interestingly, "[Word Lists](https://books.google.com/books?id=wrAmAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA388&dq=%22druthers%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_r-CM4dP0AhXXHc0KHUVuD_IQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22druthers%22&f=false)" in *Dialect Notes* (1895) identifies *druthers* as a Southern term:

> **druthers** : choice, preference. "To have one's *druthers*" = to have what one "had rather" have. "Bein's I cain't have my *druthers* an set still, I cal'late I'd better pearen up an' go 'long." South.

---

***The 'drathers' variant***

Searches for *drathers* turn up several matches from 1870 forward. From Bret Harte, "[Centrepole Bill](https://books.google.com/books?id=72WEdSmTI9kC&pg=PA85&dq=%22drathers%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi80-Grjdb0AhVZK80KHeQIBNkQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22drathers%22&f=false)," in *The Overland Monthly* (January 1870):

> There was three of us chums; and very sing'ler, we was all named Bill, and they gave us names to know us apart. I was Centrepole Bill 'cause I drove that wagon; there was Canvas Bill, as drove that wagon; and Stubby Bill, as was a general hand. We traveled and traveled until we got to Mound City in Ioway; and there Stubby was knifed for something or other in a row, and died. He and I didn't go cahoots as much as  Canvas and me, but we missed him for all o' that. We see some hubbly life, off and on, we did; and if I was a youngster, I 'drather set up in any perfession but a circus-driver, but a man can't always have his **'drathers**. Leastwise, if he could, p'r'aps he wouldn't be no better off.

In the story, Centrepole Bill specifies that he is from Maine, although it isn't clear whether his use of *drathers* is connected with his geographical origin. [Bret Harte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bret_Harte) was originally from New York, but moved to California when he was seventeen and remained there until his middle thirties, when he returned East—first to New York and then to Boston. to  *The Overland Monthly* was published in San Francisco.

From Ella Thompson, "[Dora's Trial](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=njp.32101073757971&view=1up&seq=411&skin=2021&q1=drathers)," in in *Lippincott's Magazine* (October 1881):

> "I'd rather teach school, father."
>
> "Waal, waal, folks can't always have their **'drathers** in this world. I ain't willin', and that's the end on't."

Dora's father (the second speaker in the extract above) is described in the story as a New England farmer. *Lippincott's Magazine* was published in Philadelphia. I have no information on Ella Williams Thompson other than that she published several pieces in *Lippincott's Magazine* and in various newspapers, including the *Boston Post*.

From Caroline Le Row, [*Duxberry Doings: A New England Story*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ej8eAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA36&dq=%22drathers%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjV1dHokdb0AhXjFjQIHWogCpEQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=%22drathers%22&f=false) (1884):

> "Now you're laughing at me! No, of course I have n't [tried to reform a drunkard], and I should never have the least desire to. Do you enjoy his society, Winnie, as much as you appear to?"
>
> "Why, I'm glad if I appear to," Winnie replied with animation. "I must say that if I could have had my '**'drathers**,' as Aunt Angeline says, I should have preferred a nap this afternoon to entertaining Tom Lawton ; but of course I would n't have him suspect such a a thing."

Le Row was a teacher in New York, a longtime correspondent of Mark Twain, and the author of *English as She Is Taught*, among other books.

---

***Conclusions***

It is certainly striking that the two earliest instances of the wording "if X had X's druthers" appear in the context of Uncle Remus–style dialect stories by Southern or Middle Border authors who put the phrasing in the mouths of Black characters. Nevertheless, the formulation "X can't have X's druthers" is at least 27 years older and appears multiple times in works by authors from New England.

Given that record of print occurrences, I see no reason to suppose that *druthers* as a noun originated in the South (without leaving a paper trail), then moved up to New England in the late 1850s, where it first appeared in print, and then moved back southward, this time in published works.

It seems far more probable that *druthers* as a noun originated in New England, based on "ruther" as a regional pronunciation of *rather*, linked to the *d* in "I'd/you'd/we'd/they'd/she'd/he'd ruther" and nounified either through organic folk adaptation or as a humorous innovation by B.P. Shillaber (or someone like him) that then caught on more generally. Although the latter path is not entirely implausible, the former seems to me to be somewhat more likely.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's what NOAD says:

> **druther** |ˈdrəðər| informal
>   *noun* (usu. one's druthers)
>   a person's preference in a matter : *if I had my druthers, I would prefer to be a writer.*
>   *adverb*
>   rather; by preference.
>
> ORIGIN late 19th cent.: from a U.S. regional pronunciation of I'd rather, contraction of would rather. Compare with **ruther** .
>
> **ruther** |ˈrəðər|
>   *adverb*
>   nonstandard spelling of rather , used in representing dialectal speech: : *I'd ruther walk*

Answer (score 1):

The noun 'druthers' was made popular perhaps especially by the comic strip "Lil Abner", where -- when anyone voiced a complaint "I'druther [be rich, be famous, not pay taxes, or whatever]" -- Mammy would respond "You caint have yer druthers".  Druthers are improbable preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier examples:

> **I'd *druther*** live in the woods any time, by myself, than on the best plantation in the county; though I've got a family, and a decent
> one, too.  [1833 letter in J. S. Skinner; *American Turf Register and
> Sporting Magazine*, Vol. 5, No. 1, p.40](https://www.google.com/books/edition/American_turf_register_and_sporting_maga/4ZEQAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=druther&pg=PA40&printsec=frontcover)

> VULGARISMS
>
> Which ***had*** you ***druther*** do? [John Goldsbury; *A Sequel to the Common
> School Grammar*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Sequel_to_the_Common_School_Grammar/I4oVAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=druther&pg=PA54&printsec=frontcover) (1842)

If  *had druther* was admonished in an 1842 grammar, it must have been in fairly common use, as evidenced by the 1833 letter.